# Building a page with smoothdivscroll

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I visited the lab page http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/lab.html of Thomas Kahn to see how I can build a html. On this lab page there are plenty of choices you can make. But is there an easy way to get these choices in a code? Or should I use the source code of the lab page to find it out? Can anyone give me advice?

Gijs

Answer (score 0):

Firstly download the zipped code which includes examples from [HERE](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/download.html)

You can change of the options you desire when initialising the plugin. They are all listed and explained [HERE](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/options.html)

Changing the options/settings is done when initialising the script on your page like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
            // Copy and paste your settings in here for example..
            hotSpotScrolling: false,
            visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: "always"
      });
    });
</script>
```